# In React, is it possible to modify the refs of a parent component inside a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a ref from a parent component as a property to a child component, and changing it's value on componentDidUpdate in the child. The update doesn't seem to take effect however.

Comment: Yes it possible, it would be better to share the parent & child components because you're breaking the question rules.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.